# Are these blocks according to PEP8?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pep8

are these two samples according to PEP8? Are they ugly? I read a lot of PEP8, but I still feel insecure about multiline blocks...

Personally, I think that one line per param is quite readable when there are many parameters to setup. It is easier to find the parameter and change its value... is it?

```py
tkinter.Label(
    self,
    bg='grey'
    bd=5,
    relief='ridge'
    ).pack(fill='both', exand=1)
```

```py
tkinter.Label(
    self,
    bg='grey'
    bd=5,
    relief='ridge').pack(fill='both', exand=1)
```

Comment: Personally I only do multi line when I am over the standard character limit per line of code. Or when it makes sense to for readability. In this particular case I would only write these labels in one line. That said I think this question is very opinion based and as such is probably not a good question for stack overflow. Also I do not see this example on the PEP8 page.Where did you find this example?

Comment: I tried to be like: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17. Also I´m using a Sublime Text config that automaticaly line breaks when a number of chars is reach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, they are both fine. I'm not aware of an official preference of either of them, as long as you are consistent in your project.

I also don't think there is a need for an official statement as the purpose of line braking is mainly to make the code more readable and every second case would be (from my experience) an exception where the rules don't really fit.

Also fine would be (which I usually en up with):

```
tkinter.Label(self,
              bg='grey',
              bd=5,
              relief='ridge').pack(fill='both', exand=1)
```

or

```
tkinter.Label(self, bg='grey',
              bd=5, relief='ridge').pack(fill='both', exand=1)
```

but not

```
tkinter.Label(self,
    bg='grey',
    bd=5,
    relief='ridge').pack(fill='both', exand=1)
```